# Integrate Javers auto audit to JPA/Hibernate entitymanager without spring framework (Vanilla Javers)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, javers

I am currently working on a Java project with a REST service to store data which run with jarkarta, hibernate on a wildfly application server with a mysql db. To store the data I prepare a resource that a DAO to persist entities:

Service:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService extends BasicWebServiceOperation {

    @Inject
    private UserDao repo;

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @UserRoles(values = {UserRole.ADMIN})
    public Response createOrUpdateUser(UserDTO dto) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        User newusr = modelMapper.map(dto, User.class);

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(newusr);

        if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
            response.setResponseToError(newusr, "INVALID_USER", "User with constraint violations");
        }

        try {
            repo.persist(newusr);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            response.setResponseToError(newusr, "Error", "Could not update or create user");
        }

        return createAndSendResponse();
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
public abstract class BasicDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected Class<T> inferredClass;

    public BasicDao() {

    }
    public BasicDao(Class<T> inferredClass) {
        this.inferredClass = inferredClass;
    }

    @JaversAuditable
    public void persist(T entity) {
        if(em.contains(entity)) {
            em.merge(entity);
        } else {
            em.persist(entity);
        }
    }

    @JaversAuditable
    public void delete(T entity) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

So far saving data works. Now i would like to audit every change why i decided me for javers. I have seen the [auto-audit aspects](https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#auto-audit-aspect) which would be perfect for my dao so i set the @JaversAuditable because i dont use any spring framework libraries.

So far I have tried to create a simple class that initializes javers. However I don't know how this is then automatically registered. The only way left ist, that after the .persist() i just calling javers.commit but not looks nice. Are there any ways how i can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

@JaversAuditable belongs to Spring AOP, and is not visible inside non-spring
projects, but in a non-spring project, you can use javax.interceptor to write a customized annotation to audit
your entities automatically. Something like this:

```
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JaversAuditable {
}
```

You need to change the return type of your persist method from void to Object and return your entity, as this is needed by javers in the commit method.

```
@Interceptor
@JaversAuditable
public class JaversAuditableInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private JaversConfig javersConfig;


    @AroundInvoke
    public Object auditEntities(InvocationContext context) {
        try {

            //distinguishing the name of the method on which the interceptor is called
            String methodName = context.getMethod().getName();
            Object responseEntity = context.proceed();

            //auditing the result of persist method
            if (methodName.equals("persist")) {
                Javers javers = javersConfig.getJavers();
                Iterable<Object> list = this.collectReturnedObjects(responseEntity);
                for (Object o : list) javers.commit("myUser", o);
            }

            return responseEntity;

        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new MyException();
        }
    }

    public Iterable<Object> collectReturnedObjects(Object returnedObject) {
        if (returnedObject instanceof Iterable) {
            return (Iterable) returnedObject;
        }

        return Lists.immutableListOf(returnedObject);
    }
}
```

This audits the changes inside the persist method. For auditing the
changes inside delete method you should add another block to this
interceptor for your delete method.